# Add WCF To Windows 8 Embedded Standard

Tags: windows-8, windows-embedded-8

I have got a Windows 8 Embedded Standard machine that has IIS installed. However, WCF-HTTP-Activation is not installed.

Get-WindowsOptionalFeature yields:

[image: Optional features]

I've tried running the command below (copied sxs folder from complete Win 8 ISO), but it errored out:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:WCF-HTTP-Activation /source:C:\Sources\sxs
```

Is it possible to add features to a Windows 8 Embedded installation, that were not included when the image was made?

Comment: C:\Sources\sxs only includes .net 3.5 files. Remove this source parameter and let Windows download the files over WU